# what encryption does myetherwallet use?

Tags: myetherwallet, encryption

I am trying to use the **encrypted ethereum** private key created by myetherwallet within my application. Everytime I need to send money, I will input my password so that my application can decrypt it and send money when required. But I need to know how can I decrypt it using the key(password) I used to create the account.

I am trying to see if anyone know what encryption (encryption method) does myetherwallet is using?

Answer (score 1):

MyEtherWallet, like most ethereum wallets, follows the [Secret Storage Definition](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Web3-Secret-Storage-Definition). The result is a JSON file which contains the encrypted key, and the parameter definitions used in its encryption.